# How to bring Configurations menuitem in Settings menuitem to my module?

Tags: python, odoo

I want to bring Configurations menuitem in Settings menuitem to my module. I mean, I want to create the menuitem in my module like configurations menuitem

[image: figure]

Sorry for my bad English. Thank all

Comment: If ans is what you are looking for then plz make it as right ans.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code in you xml file

```
<menuitem id="menu_configuration" name="Configurations" />
<menuitem id="menu_sub_config" name="Sub Configurations" parent="menu_configuration" />
```